# some weird stff im running into on java

Tags: java

So im working on java codingbat and this is the question:

Given a string, look for a mirror image (backwards) string at both the beginning and end of the given string.
In other words, zero or more characters at the very begining of the given string, and at the very end of the string in reverse order (possibly overlapping).

**For example:**
 the string "abXYZba" has the mirror end "ab".   mirrorEnds("abXYZba") → "ab" mirrorEnds("abca") → "a" mirrorEnds("aba") → "aba" .

My code passed all the test except for the other test, which is not specified. I dont know what's wrong with it.

```
  public String mirrorEnds(String string) {
  String input = string, mirror = "";
            int length = string.length();


            for (int n = 0; n < (length+1) / 2; n++) {


                if (input.charAt(n) != input.charAt(length - n - 1)) {

                    break;
                }else if(length%2 == 1 && n == (length - 1)/2){
//                    System.out.println("length/2 = " );

                    return input;
                } 
                else {
                    mirror += input.charAt(n);
                }
            }

            return  mirror;
}
```

Comment: Translate somebody please: *some weird stff im ...*

Comment: What's the expected output for a String with single character?

Comment: Is it only me or anyone else also don't see any question out there?

Comment: "_except for the other test_ " Where is that test?

Answer (score 1):

You were correct in not needing to go though the entire word, but your logic is more complex than it needs to be, making it harder to find and fix the problem.  The root cause of the test failure is in the last `return` statement.  It must return `string` if the loop completes without breaking.  You can fix your code by changing `break;` to `return  mirror;` and changing the last `return mirror;` to `return input;`

The test that is failing is one like this:

```
 mirrorEnds("abba") -> "abba"
```

A much simpler version of your code can be created like this:

```
public String mirrorEnds(String string) {
    int len =  string.length();
    for (int i=0; i < len/2; ++i)
        if (string.charAt(i) != string.charAt(len - 1 - i))
            return string.substring(0, i);
    return string;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

mirrorEnds("abba")?

Anyways, I'm sure you could come up with a better question name than "some weird stuff"...

Answer (score 0):

Since you are dividing n by 2 in your loop termination condition, it will end when halfway through the word.  This is enough to tell the word is a palindrome, but not enough to build your output correctly.  You have a condition handling palindrome with odd numbers of letter, but not even numbers of letters.  I believe the failing test will be of the form "abba", where I believe what you have will return "ab", instead of "abba".

If you change you loop to:

```
for (int n = 0; n < length; n++) {
```

I believe it should be doing what you want.  This also makes the short circuit case unnecessary, so:

```
        for (int n = 0; n < length; n++) {
            if (input.charAt(n) != input.charAt(length - n - 1)) {
                break;
            } 
            else {
                mirror += input.charAt(n);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

The first test I tried was with the string `"abba"` which fails. It returns ab, and not abba. As femtoRgon mentioned, you're not going through the entire word, which may some times be necessary. femtoRgon's solution works, as well as taking a slightly different approach to iterating through the word as follows:

```
public String mirrorEnds(String string) {
    boolean matches = true;
    StringBuilder mirrorEnd = new StringBuilder();
    int index = 0;
    while (matches && index < string.length()) {
        if (string.charAt(index) == string.charAt(string.length() - index - 1))
            mirrorEnd.append(string.charAt(index));
        else
            matches = false;
        index++;
    }
    return mirrorEnd.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public String mirrorEnds(String string) {
  String comp="";
  for(int i=0; i<string.length(); i++){
   if(string.charAt(i)==string.charAt(string.length()-(i+1)))
    comp= comp+ string.charAt(i);
   else break;
  }
  return comp;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please consider editing your post to add more explanation about what your code does and why it will solve the problem. An answer that mostly just contains code (even if it's working) usually wont help the OP to understand their problem.

Comment: I am so sorry...this is my first answer on stackoverflow can I be given a slack on this one... thanks